# Perl script in bin that inserts a file

Tags: perl

I have a script `~/bin/script`

```
$ cat ~/bin/script
#!/bin/bash

perl -pe 's/loremipsum/`cat ~/foo/bar/file.txt`/ge' -i ~/path/to/target.txt
```

The script is supposed to replace every instance of `loremipsum` in `target.txt` with the contents of `file.txt`. However, issuing `script` returns

```
Backticks found where operator expected at -e line 1, at end of line
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Can't find string terminator "`" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

You should store your backtick result in a script variable and use it in the perl call, like

```
REPL = `cat ~/foo/bar/file.txt`
perl -pe "s/loremipsum/$REPL/ge" -i ~/path/to/target.txt
```

But I think it would be better to use a perl script only to replace the string with the content of a file, because the content of foo/bar/file.txt can damage your command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

perl -pe "s/loremipsum/`cat ~/foo/bar/file.txt`/ge" -i ~/path/to/target.txt
```

Seems like you have problems with the singles quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by replacing `~` with the path to your home directory.

Or, you could use

```
perl -pe '$thing=`cat "$ENV{HOME}/file.txt"`;s/loremipsum/$thing/g' target.txt
```

or some other, *nicer*, construct that first reads the contents of your file and then replaces the string with that value.

---

`sed` is another choice of tool for this, and it even has a special command to read in another file:

```
sed '/loremipsum/{
         r file.txt
         d
     }' target.txt
```

This replaces the *line* that contains the text `loremipsum` with the contents of `file.txt`.

Given the file `target.txt`,

```
some text
some text loremipsum
some more text
```

and the file `file.txt`,

```
This text
is inserted
```

the command would produce

```
some text
This text
is inserted
some more text
```